# Lag exactly every 60 seconds

Tags: router, lag

I have been having lag issues when I play online games (Mostly League of Legends). I've been suffering from lag that occurs exactly every 60 seconds and it lasts 1-3 seconds. I called my ISP and they cant find the issue on their end.  We use a wireless broadband service due to the fact we live out in the country. They are usually very good about finding and fixing problems that occur. I am thinking it may be a router issue, but I am not sure. What could cause this and how can I fix it? I am wired in with an Ethernet cable and everyone on in the household gets this lag. It just started happening one day and its been going on for about two weeks. My router is an Asus N65R. I am not the best at problem solving the computers, but I can navigate through one pretty well with the right instructions. Thanks in advance and let me know what more information you need.

Comment: What does your network layout look like?  I'm guessing there is a 3G modem and then your router attached to that?  If so, have you tried removing the router and connecting your pc directly to the 3G modem?

Answer (score 2):

Someone turned on or installed something that "checks in" every minute, I'd guess. What, exactly, I don't know - email, horrid crudwear (weather-checkers, various spybots, etc.)

Check if it happens on each computer with all the other computers turned off, to see if you can isolate it to a particular computer.

Check anything you (or anyone in the household) knowingly installed in the last two weeks. Check antivirus status to make sure something else didn't install itself in the last two weeks. Sign up for any new services/"features" on any sort of social media? etc...

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for getting high ping (lag) value:

1. High ping is when there is high traffic in your system.
2. This can be either caused by loading such large files that the system cannot handle them, or by running several programs at the same time.
3. High ping is not just due to the bad Internet connection. Video lag, sound lag, virus, spyware, worms, and so on, could cause the high ping. Not enough RAM could cause the problem too.

If you get any high ping, try to lower your ping rate by using some of the following instructions:

1. Don't open any video streams and check if there is any problem in your router.
2. Make sure there's no browser .exe's still running in task manager.
3. Try to contact your Internet service provider and get suitable data plan.
4. Use any software like Game Booster
5. Move closer to server

If you follow these suggestions, you will reduce your ping rate.  Finally, you can check your new ping using http://www.whoisxy.com/ping.aspx